# IntelliJ IDEA 15 not recognizing java.time

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sdk, java-8

I have the current version of IntelliJ Idea and have already checked that the SDK is 1.8. However, when I import java.time.*, all of the methods are red and give the message "Cannot resolve symbol", despite there not being an error on the actual import. I have included a screenshot of my code instead of a nicely formatted version of my code because I believe the error is with Intellij/Java and not the actual code itself. If more detail is needed I can provide screenshots of the settings. I just don't know how to proceed and I haven't been able to find anything on the internet that answers my question.

[image: Here is a picture or the problem]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with IntelliJ. `now()` is a static method of `LocalDateTime` so you should call (without the *new*):

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
```

Your call with *new* keyword makes the compiler search for an inner class named `now` within the `LocalDateTime` class which it wants to instantiate.